# Javascript removes letters duplicates and sequence in string

Tags: javascript, regex

There are many posts like this and I have found a few solutions but there are not perfect.
One of them:

```
"aabbhahahahahahahahahahahasetsetset".replace(/[^\w\s]|(.+)\1+/gi, '$1')
```

The results is:

```
abhahahahahahaset
```

I want to get result:

```
abhaset
```

How to do this ?

Comment: Our answers fix your specific problem. But I wonder, what is your desired output for `abcabcDabcabcD`. Do you want `abcDabcD` or `abcabcD`? So longest, or shortest repetition if there are nested repetitions.

Comment: Hmm, good question. I want your string to be abcD

Comment: Ah okay, then just run the replacement until it doesn't change any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.+` is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy). It takes as much as it can. That is half of the `ha`s so that `\1` can match the second half. Making the repetition ungreedy should do the trick:

```
/[^\w\s]|(.+?)\1+/gi
```

By the way, the `i` doesn't change anything here.

To get rid of nested repetitions (e.g. transform `aaBBaaBB` into `aB` (via `aaBB` or `aBaB`)) simply run the replacement multiple times until the result does not change any more.

```
var pattern = /[^\w\s]|(.+?)\1+/g;

var output = "aaBBaaBB";
var input;

do
{
    input = output;
    output = input.replace(pattern, "$1");
} while (input != output)
```

I admit the naming of `output` is a bit awkward for the first repetition, but you know... the two most difficult problems in computer science are cache invalidation, naming things and off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 2):

`.+` will match the *maximum* amount possible, so `hahahaha` satisfies `(.+)\1` with `haha` and `haha`.  You want to match the *minimum* amount possible, so use a reluctant quantifier.

```
"aabbhahahahahahahahahahahasetsetset".replace(/[^\w\s]|(.+?)\1+/gi, '$1')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HQRDg/

Comment: Thank you very much, but m.buettner was first :)